# Basic Regex Practice

Tags: java, regex

A simple question I was unable to find any similar examples which did not recommend using outside libraries, I have an exercise in which we have mock data similar to HTML/XML and we are restricted to using only Java regex library to parse and manipulate it. 
We want to translate the data into a map. The format is:

```
<key> data words here </key>...
```

...where each data word will be added to the map with the key separately, so the resulting map should look like this:

```
{key, data
key, words
key, here}
```

I have come up with some solutions which first find and store the key using a regex, then match the inside of the key tag, store that data in a string, tokenize it using a space and bracket delimiters, and loop through the resulting list to write to the map. Is there a more straightforward or elegant method of doing this where I could capture the key and an array/list of the data words using just regex and eliminating the use of the tokenizer?

Some sample data below (notice there are no nested tags which makes this much simpler than parsing HTML):

```
<author> A. Cau, R. Kuiper, and W.-P. de Roever. </author>
<title> Formalising Dijkstra's development strategy within Stark's formalism. </title>
<editor> In C. B. Jones, R. C. Shaw, and T. Denvir, editors, </editor>
<booktitle> Proc. 5th. BCS-FACS Refinement Workshop, </booktitle>
<date> 1992. </date>
```

(all on one line - line breaks added for readability)

Comment: What are you using now? Perhaps we can look at streamlining it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the following regex captures the tag name and its value in group `\1` or `\2`:

```
<([^>/]+)>(.*?)</\1>
```

**EXPLAINED**

`<` - match `<` literally

`([^>/]+)` - match and capture everything that is not a `>` or `/` which avoids closing tags

`>` - match `>` literally

`(.*?)` - match and capture anything non-greedily

`</\1>` - match closing tag

Comment: This is more what I was looking for, however I guess I do not grasp how the multiple captures work. Will this return a 2-d array rather than a regular array as with a single capture? If i run the regex on a line with multiple tags will it be [0][0] first the first tag, [0][1] second tag, [1][0] first data, [1][1] second tag data and so on?